# Delphi: Load bass.dll directly from memory via BTMemoryModule and play sound from resources

Tags: delphi, memory, audio, bass.dll

hello i try load dll into memory and play sound file from resources (Delphi2009). In this example i load dll from HDD to memory (i plan to load dll from resources to memory) but i got an error after Button1Click

*First chance exception at $76E2C41F. Exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000'. Process DemoApp.exe (3020)*

Sound doesn't play at all :/

some of code i used from here: http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/14360/blog1682.html#a_codemodez
but i couldn't compile it due to custom units strUtilz, MemModuleUnicode

---

BTMemoryModule v0.0.41 includes BTMemoryModule and also examples

http://code.google.com/p/memorymodule/downloads/list

BTMemoryModule v.1 (old probably) (with BTMemoryModule + BTMemoryModuleUnicode)

http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/btmemorymodule

---

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, BTMemoryModule, StdCtrls, xpman;

 const // Constants :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::
 _s = '';
 _n=#13#10; // line break
 ver = '1.0 '; // Articles
 tit = 'Bass Memory App' + ver; // title - the name of the application
 msgYN=$04; msgERR=$10; msgINF=$40; // <-type codes posts
 res1='dll'; // resource name with dllkoy
 res2='snd'; // name of the resource with sound

 type // TYPES :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::::::::
 MemRes = record // structure for the projection of the resource in memory
 p: pointer; // pointer to the memory
 sz: int64; // size (length)
 rd: cardinal; // hResData
 ri: cardinal; // hResInfo
 end;

type
  TBASS_ChannelPlay = function (handle: cardinal; restart: bool): bool; stdcall;
  TBASS_StreamCreateFile = function (mem: bool; f: Pointer; offset, length: int64; flags: cardinal): cardinal; stdcall;
  TBASS_StreamFree = function (handle: cardinal): bool; stdcall;
  TBASS_Init = function (device: integer; freq, flags: cardinal; win: cardinal; clsid: pGUID): bool; stdcall;
  TBASS_Free = function: bool; stdcall;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    BtnFileCAll: TButton;
    BtnMemCall: TButton;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    mp_DllData : Pointer;
    m_DllDataSize : Integer;
    mp_MemoryModule: PBTMemoryModule;
    //m_DllHandle: Cardinal;

    m_BASS_ChannelPlay: TBASS_ChannelPlay;
    m_BASS_StreamCreateFile: TBASS_StreamCreateFile;
    //m_BASS_StreamFree: TBASS_StreamFree;
    m_BASS_Init: TBASS_Init;
    //m_BASS_Free: TBASS_Free;
  public
    { Public declarations }


  end;

var
 Form1: TForm1;
 wnd: cardinal; // window handle
 ss: cardinal; // handle audio stream
 snd: MemRes; // pointer to the audio file in memory
 dll: MemRes; // pointer to memory dllku
 bass: Pointer; // structure projection dll in memory
 stp: word; // execution step (for debug)
 st: boolean; // status of the audio stream
 th: cardinal; // handle the flow of replacement buttons
 ti: cardinal; // id flow
 ms : TMemoryStream;
 rs : TResourceStream;

implementation


{$R *.dfm}
{$R BassMem.RES}  // snd CookieJarLoop.ogg RCData

function Res2Mem(hInst:cardinal;res:string;rtype:pChar):MemRes;
begin
  result.p:=nil;
  result.ri:=FindResource(hInst,pchar(res),rtype);
  if result.ri=0 then exit;
  result.sz:=SizeOfResource(hInst,result.ri);
  if result.sz=0 then exit;
  result.rd:=LoadResource(hInst,result.ri);
  if result.rd=0 then exit;
  result.p:=LockResource(result.rd);
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Position := poScreenCenter;
  MemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  MemoryStream.LoadFromFile('bass.dll');
  MemoryStream.Position := 0;
  m_DllDataSize := MemoryStream.Size;
  mp_DllData := GetMemory(m_DllDataSize);
  MemoryStream.Read(mp_DllData^, m_DllDataSize);
  MemoryStream.Free;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeMemory(mp_DllData);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mp_MemoryModule := BTMemoryLoadLibary(mp_DllData, m_DllDataSize);
    try
    if mp_MemoryModule = nil then showmessage('err1');

    @m_BASS_Init := BTMemoryGetProcAddress(mp_MemoryModule, 'BASS_Init');
    if @m_BASS_Init = nil then showmessage('err2');

    @m_BASS_ChannelPlay := BTMemoryGetProcAddress(mp_MemoryModule, 'BASS_ChannelPlay');
    if @m_BASS_ChannelPlay = nil then showmessage('err3');

    m_BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, Handle, nil);

    snd:=Res2Mem(hInstance, res2 ,RT_RCDATA);

    ss:=m_BASS_StreamCreateFile(true,snd.p,0,snd.sz,4{=BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP});
    if ss=0 then showmessage('err ss=0');
    m_BASS_ChannelPlay(ss, false);

    except
    Showmessage('An error occoured while loading the dll: ' + BTMemoryGetLastError);
    end;
  if mp_MemoryModule <> nil then BTMemoryFreeLibrary(mp_MemoryModule);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not initialise `m_BASS_StreamCreateFile`. Consequently it has the value `nil` when you call it. Which explains the error message.

You need to add a call to `BTMemoryGetProcAddress` to initialise `m_BASS_StreamCreateFile`.

```
@m_BASS_StreamCreateFile := BTMemoryGetProcAddress(mp_MemoryModule, 
  'BASS_StreamCreateFile');
if @m_BASS_StreamCreateFile = nil then ....
```

This would have been simple enough to discover had you run the code under the debugger. The exception would have been trapped by the debugger and the call stack will have led to the call of `m_BASS_StreamCreateFile`. You could then have inspected its value to discover that it was `nil`.

Comment: I got another error "access violation at 0x77118dc9: write of adress 0x00000014" , i tried run compiled release it played broken sound for a 1 sec then it crashed. I looks like problem with BTMemory, i tried call dll from HDD and sound played without problem.

Comment: I think I answered the question that you asked. That said, I wonder why you unload the DLL. I bet the sound plays async. Remove the call that unloads the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all: **Nafalem**, your code is terrible =\
As **David Heffernan** said before - there are missing initialization for m_BASS_StreamCreateFile; but also: what did you expected to do with `if mp_MemoryModule <> nil then MemFreeLibrary(mp_MemoryModule);` just right after `m_BASS_ChannelPlay`???
Just think a bit - you starting to play sound and then removing library from memory...
You need to move MemFreeLibrary into FormDestory before `FreeMemory(mp_DllData);`.

But sadly, even fixing your code isn't enough to make it work.
As i said in my article (http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/14360/blog1682.html (sry, i'm too lazy to translate it to English)):
there are a bug inside the BTMemoryModule:

```
  if (l_section.Characteristics and IMAGE_SCN_MEM_DISCARDABLE) <> 0 then begin
      // section is not needed any more and can safely be freed
      VirtualFree(Pointer(l_section.Misc.PhysicalAddress), l_section.SizeOfRawData, MEM_DECOMMIT);
      inc(longword(l_section), sizeof(TImageSectionHeader));
      continue;
  end;
```

this part of code frees sections with enabled Discardable-flag, but it shouldn't be done in our case!
As you can find in msdn, discardable-flag means that *section can be discarded as needed*, as you see it CAN be discarded, not MUST be... and it's for physical PE-files, which could be readed from file on demand!
 If speak more bout this, Discardable-flag was used in 16-bit Windows and it was saying that its contents may be not uploaded into the swap, and readed from a file, if necessary. In the 32-bit Win OS and higher versions system looks priorly at IMAGE_SCN_MEM_NOT_PAGED, so just leave discardable-flag to low-core driver development, and never use it in user-mode PE-modules.

P.S. >

> i couldn't compile it due to custom units strUtilz, MemModuleUnicode

just download archive from my article, it contains MemModule with my fixes, as to strUtilz - just replace it with SysUtils, i wrote in comments that it's simply a module with str/int conversion-routines coded in asm.

//Sorry for my dirty English =P